# How to fix image size

Tags: css, wordpress, image

This is my friends website that I am helping her with redlady.al, I am using http://thevoux.fuelthemes.net/ theme, 
My problem is the top post carousel, images display in different sizes and they should display like in the theme demo.
I have contacted the theme developer and it seems he doesnt have an answer for it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1 (CSS)

Set `.slick.slick-initialized .post` to fixed height, I'm using `280px` here:

[image]

Downsides: if there's more text 300px might not be enough.

### Solution 2 (Photshop/Gimp)

Simply crop the images in Photoshop before uploading them so their height is always the same.

Downside: you have to do that for every image.

### Solution 3 (CSS)

Set `.slick-slide img` height to so it equals the height of the tallest image in your slider.

Downside: as these are images and you can't use `background-size` proportions might get weird in some cases. You need to use images with the same proportions to avoid that.

[image]

I'd personally go with 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
.slick.slick-initialized .post{
    visibility: visible;
    height: 369px;
}
.slick-slide img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}
```

Setting height to exactly the size of Voux page + some quick image tweaks fixed the issue for me. Keep in mind this will stretch images that are not wide enough.

This will get you starting, I came up with this in like 30sec, if you want perfect solution you should hire some one.